# Solving the 8 puzzle using A* - how to break ties?

Tags: java, algorithm, sliding-tile-puzzle

Currently working on solving the 8 puzzle using an A* algorithm. The [assignment](http://coursera.cs.princeton.edu/algs4/assignments/8puzzle.html) asks that we use the A* algorithm with the Manhattan priority to solve the puzzle. But I can across this particular scenario where there's a tie between the two possible neighbor boards (see below), how do I proceed?

Starting with

{{2,3,5}, {1,0,4}, {7,8,6}}

Eventually we come down to choosing between these two:

[image]

If we choose to break the tie by using the Hamming distance, the 2nd choice would be chosen and will not lead us to the solution, but how do we know we should choose the first board?

Comment: What do you mean "will not lead us to the solution"? A* involves searching multiple paths, some of which will turn out not to be optimal. It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry, I think I might have misunderstood the algorithm. So basically, you keep on dequeueing the lowest priority board, exploring multiple paths until the board that's dequeued is the goal, and then you obtain the shortest path by back-tracing from the goal board?

Comment: Yes, that's the right idea now.

Comment: Can't thank you enough, your comment helped me realize my mistake, I'm done the assignment now and it's working fine now, thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made the mistake of thinking the solution is gonna be the sequence of boards dequeued. Turns out you have to back track from the goal board when it's dequeued, problem solved!